# database search best performances

Tags: database, database-schema

how can i do a search based on combinations of like 50 parameters like filters.
These filters can be price color size brand etc.
So we can get different pages based on these params.
So one link can have price brand size, another one size brand color, and so on.
My question is what will be the best practice to query the database based on these params.
I have one ideea to encrypt them into 101101101 sequence of 1 and 0 and search by that.

So i have like more than 2 milions possible combinations, and i want to reduce the query time.
I heard about btree but i don't know how to use it, i have given my table columns the proper indexes but from this point i don't know in wich direction should i go. How my query is going to look like.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. Please provide more details.

Comment: You need to be specific in your questions on SO, ask questions that will allow a concise answer. This is really too broad at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is a good idea to "encrypt" the params, but don't do it like "10100010", because then you'll have to be storing these values as string.
Rather encode it as base10 number. It means that 100101 = 1*32+0*16+0*8+1*4+0*2+1*1 = 37.
Ofcourse, with 50 flags you'd get a number too big to store as bigint (which is 32 bytes), so try to logically group the parameters and use 2-3 fields for them.
The problem with this aproach would be with querying the data - you would have to write a function extracting a flag from the number, to be able to query the data by only one parameter and not all of them.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the ideea, but i think that btree it is the best. So what i'm doing right now is to add indexes to table columns but from this point i'm lost about btree search. So the problem will resume of something like having n amount of rows and finding a search algor that will be consistent no matter how many rows are there.